# Using hide($submitted); in a tpl?

Tags: entities, nodes, theming

Right now I'm working in a tpl file and in a specific place I have `<?php print render($submitted); ?>` and this works just fine. However, later when I do `<?php print render($content); ?>` it will render the submitted by link there as well. Normally I just:

```
<?php
  hide($content["comments"]);
  hide($submitted); //this does not work like it does with hiding comments and links
  print render($content);
?>
```

However, the copying the way to do it for comments and links does not work with submitted and it continues to render the submitted by in the content.

Comment: Oh and btw if I hide the option for showing the submitted by link on the content type then it won't render in my first instance either, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There must be 2 variables holding the "submitted" string, `$submitted` and also `$content['submitted']`. You should either forget the `$submitted` variable and if you `render($content['submitted'])` then it should put that as `#printed => true`. Then later if you `render($content)` it shouldn't print the submitted text as it's already printed.

The second option would be to `render($submitted)` and then do `hide($content['submitted'])` before `render($content)`.